# Alinhar essas imagens e textos HTML e CSS do jeito "correto"

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu tenho que fazer meu TCC e em uma das páginas eu tenho que alinhar uma imagem, um ícone e um titulo um por cima do outro (foto), eu consigo fazer isso mas com muitos códigos que julgo desnecessários para algo simples porque sei que tem como fazer com pouca coisa e de um jeito mais "correto", até agora to usando assim e está horrível na parte dos títulos e dos ícones:
Link das fotos e como o site esta até agora:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qR2WBE6ORpdbzPFyPAEql12lBIVD2gz1

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="imagens">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="imagens/igrejaF.png" class="iconeC">
            <h1 class="tit">Administração</h1>
            <img src="imagens/hotelariaMob.png" class="imagens">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="imagens/macaF.png" class="iconeC">
            <h1 class="tit2">Análises Clínicas</h1>
            <img src="imagens/fisicaMob.png" class="imagens">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="imagens/fogueteF.png" class="iconeC" id="foguete">
            <h1 class="tit" id="tit3">Contabilidade</h1>
            <img src="imagens/astroMob.png" class="imagens">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="imagens/lampadaF.png" class="iconeC" id="lampada">
            <h1 class="tit2" id="tit4">Design de Interiores</h1>
            <img src="imagens/eletroMob.png" class="imagens">
        </a>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#imagens{
    margin-top:12%;
    margin-left:0.7%;
    width: 100%;
}

.iconeC{
    position:absolute;
    width:14%;
    margin-left:18%;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.imagens{
    filter: sepia(60%) blur(1.3px) brightness(54%);
    float: left;
    margin-left:  3%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.tit{
    font-family: Roboto-Thin;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 22%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    position: absolute;
}
.tit2{
    font-family: Roboto-Thin;
    font-family: Roboto-Thin;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    position:  absolute;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 51%;
    margin-top: 22%;
}
#tit3{
    margin-top: 52%;
}
#tit4{
    margin-top: 52%;
}
#foguete{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-top: 37%;
    width: 14%;
}
#lampada{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 68%;
    margin-top: 36%;
    width: 10%;
}
```

[image: Foto da página como tem que ficar]

Comment: Existem várias forma de fazer isso... Precisa ser responsivo? tem que funcionar no IE? pode mudar a estrutura das tags html ou só pode mexer no css?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um modelo bem simples usando `Display:Flex`. Tentei usar algumas coisas do seu código, mas não fiquei preso a isso, como vc falou tentei simplificar e otimizar o código para vc não ter que se preocupar com tamanhos de Títulos ou de imagens, pois tudo sempre vai ficar alinhado independente dos tamanho de altura e largura com vc pode ver no exemplo abaixo.

Não apenas copie e cole, leia o código, brinque com ele, apague uma coisa e acrescente outros, vai testando as propriedades para entender bem o que foi feito, pois essa pode ser uma basa para vc usar no futuro.

Execute tb em "Página toda" para ver que ele vai alinha de forma responsiva

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 50%; 
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container .wrapper {
    min-width: calc(50% - 2rem);
    margin: 1rem;
    height: auto;
    /* background-color: #ff0000; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
.box img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
.cont {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.cont h5 {
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    font-family: Roboto-Thin, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/250/150" alt="">
                <div class="cont">
                    <img src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" alt="">
                    <h5>paralelelpípedo</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/150/150" alt="">
                <div class="cont">
                    <img src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" alt="">
                    <h5>Tit Lorem, ipsum.</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/150/250" alt="">
                <div class="cont">
                    <img src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" alt="">
                    <h5>Tit123</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/250/150" alt="">
                <div class="cont">
                    <img src="http://placeskull.com/50/50" alt="">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se é suposto meter o ícone e o texto por cima da imagem penso que isto funcione, vi na internet, pode testar.

```
<img id="imagem" src="www.link.com/imagem.jpg"/>
<div id="texto">Texto que fica sobre a imagem</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma pequena solução responsiva. Bastou utilizar as propriedades *Position Absolute e Position Relative*. Quanto aos ícones, basta salvá-los todos em proporção quadrada, independente do tamanho irá se adequar ao layout.

Veja no exemplo:

```css
#content {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.boxImagens {
  width: 46%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  margin: 2%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.imagens {
  filter: sepia(60%) blur(1.3px) brightness(54%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.boxDesc {
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 11% 25%;
  position: absolute;
}
.icon {
  width: 60%;
}
.descTitle {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="imagens">

    <a href="#" class="boxImagens">
      <div class="boxDesc">
        <img src="http://www.socialmusic.com.br/v3/wp-content/themes/meutema/images/icones/icon-instagram.png" class="icon">
        <h1 class="descTitle">Administração</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://static.todamateria.com.br/upload/57/b7/57b7235c6af22-paisagem-natural.jpg" class="imagens">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="boxImagens">
      <div class="boxDesc">
        <img src="http://www.socialmusic.com.br/v3/wp-content/themes/meutema/images/icones/icon-instagram.png" class="icon">
        <h1 class="descTitle">Administração</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://static.todamateria.com.br/upload/57/b7/57b7235c6af22-paisagem-natural.jpg" class="imagens">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="boxImagens">
      <div class="boxDesc">
        <img src="http://www.socialmusic.com.br/v3/wp-content/themes/meutema/images/icones/icon-instagram.png" class="icon">
        <h1 class="descTitle">Administração</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://static.todamateria.com.br/upload/57/b7/57b7235c6af22-paisagem-natural.jpg" class="imagens">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="boxImagens">
      <div class="boxDesc">
        <img src="http://www.socialmusic.com.br/v3/wp-content/themes/meutema/images/icones/icon-instagram.png" class="icon">
        <h1 class="descTitle">Administração</h1>
      </div>
      <img src="https://static.todamateria.com.br/upload/57/b7/57b7235c6af22-paisagem-natural.jpg" class="imagens">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Vale ressaltar que setei um `width` fixo no `#content` depois você precisa alterar conforme seu layout.